# How to create a dictionary containing the values changed via pandas ".cat.codes" function

Tags: python, pandas

I did this:

`df.abc = df.abc.astype('category').cat.codes`

All the unique values in my `abc` column were assigned an Integer value.

Example:
`"TV" = 0, "Smartphone"=1, "Video Games"=2`

I just want to create a dictionary variable automatically containing the values like this:

`{0:"TV",1:"Smartphone",2:"Video Games"}`